# How to change the text of an element to the first line of a text document?

Tags: html

Excuse me as this is probably a silly request, but I'm working on a school project where I need the status of a text file (either "yes" or "no") to confirm whether the user has visited the site before.

Can someone help me with the code for 1) reading the text file and 2) setting the element's text to that when the page loads?

Thanks - I have reasonable HTML and visual basic knowledge but I can't seem to figure this out.

**If you need all my code just ask for it and I can provide it.**

Edit: if anyone also has any suggestions of how to do this a different way I will take them as well.

Comment: Yeah we will need the relevant code you have so far, and an example of the contents in your file. From the sounds of it, you'll need javascript (preferrably jQuery).

Comment: If this is to be stored client-side, I'd suggest using `localStorage` or a cookie; or is this stored server-side? Incidentally we will almost always need to see your "[mcve]" code (not **all** code) just the minimum for us to reproduce your problem) to provide useful answers; for further guidance take a look at the "[ask]" guidelines too.

Comment: @DavidThomas The idea to use cookies was great and I've got it working. However, my .html files are stored in the "C:/Website" directory -  "C:/Website/index.html", for example. For cookies they must be stored in the main website - would that be "C:/Website"?